# How do you import a variable from the main actions panel to a class file?

Tags: class, flash, import, action, panel

I've searched long for this one, but nobody seems to give a clear answer. I'm a beginner, and I want to import a variable from the main "F9" actions panel  into a class file so it can read it (example: in main .fla file, I have a variable var myNumber:Number = 1; how would I import it into a class file so the program can read it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a “Document Class”. In this class you can place your variable. Where will you use `myNumber` variable?

[image]

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public var myNumber:Number = 1;

        public function Main()
        { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "share" your variable when you create an instance of your class by passing it in the class constructor, or using any other public function.

Take this example :

**MyClass.as :**

```
package  {

    public class MyClass {

        private var number:int;

        public function MyClass(num:int = 0) {
            // assign the value of the variable to a private one for a later use
            this.number = num;
            // use directly the value of the variable
            trace('the number is passed in the constructor : ' + num);
        }

        public function set_number(num:int):void {
            // assign the value of the variable to a private one for a later use
            this.number = num;
        }

        public function use_number(num:int):void {
            // use the value of the variable
            trace(num + ' x ' + num + ' = ' + (num * num));
        }

    }

}
```

**test.fla :**

```
import MyClass;

var my_number:int = 1234;

var my_class:MyClass = new MyClass(my_number);  // using the class constructor

    my_class.set_number(my_number);             // using a function to set a private var value

    my_class.use_number(my_number);             // using a function to do some operations
```

Hope that can help.